# Ruby arrays and non-incremental indexes

Tags: ruby, arrays

I have an array in ruby, and I am setting the index to id of object like below.

My first question is:

This code works:

```
@array = Array.new(@objects.size)
for i in 0...@objects.size
  @array[i] = @objects[i].value
end
```

but when I do:

```
 @array[@objects[i].id] = @objects[i].value
```

it says:

> undefined method [] for nil::NilClass

I tried putting 100 or 1000 instead of `i` to make sure it's not about "index out of range", but those worked, I tried converting `id` to int by using `to_i` even though it should already be an int, but it still doesn't work. I don't get it.

My second question is:

If I get to make the ids work, does saying `Array.new(@objects.size)` become usless?

I am not using indexes 0 to size but IDs, so what is happening? Is it initializing indexes `0...size` to `nil` or is it just creating a space for up to x objects?

EDIT:

So I've been told it is better to use Hash for this, and I agree, But I still seem to have the same error in the same situation (just changed `Array.new(@objects.size)`to`Hash.new`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thats not how Arrays work in Ruby. You can however use a hash to do this, and look them up using the method you want:

```
@lookup_hash = Hash.new
for i in 0...@objects.size
  @lookup_hash[@objects[i].id] = @objects[i].value
end
```

Now you can do:

```
@lookup_hash[@some_object.id]
```

And it will return that object's value as you have stored it.

**Additional Info**

You could also rewrite your loop like this, since you dont need the index anymore:

```
@lookup_hash = Hash.new
@objects.each do |obj|
  @lookup_hash[obj.id] = obj.value
end
```

A little bit more readable in my opinion.

Comment: Still seems to give me the same error, I tried doing p @objects[i].id it prints 2. When i hard code 2 for the hash key, it works, but when i use the @objects[i].id it says undefined method [] for nil::NilClass

Comment: Both Array and Hash have a `[]` method for looking up items they contain. The nil::NilClass error may indicate you are trying to use that on something that isn't one of those, so maybe a typo, or something? Can you re-post the code you are using maybe using http://pastie.org/ so it doesn't get lost in the comment formatting

Comment: Sounds like you're calling `[]` on `nil`.

Comment: It can't be a typo I'm just swapping the indexes to a hardcoded number and it works,  I even tried printing the id. I will paste teh real code in a second.

Comment: In ruby <1.9 .id is a method on Object - everything has a .id. In this case it's confusing, maybe it causes the unexpected nil.

Answer (score 1):

Your're trying to use an array like a hash. Try this:

```
Hash[@objects.map{|o| [o.id, o.value] }]
```

Take a look at the [Array](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Array.html) and [Hash](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Hash.html) documentations.

Answer (score 1):

1. `@array = @objects.map { |obj| obj.value }`
2. You can, but you don't need to specify the size when creating an array. Anyway, try to use the functional capabilities of Ruby (map, select, inject) instead of C-like imperative loops.

Comment: what would my array contain? how will it understand i just want a certain value from the object

Comment: @Ave. Try it so you can see how it works. Map is the fundamental operation of funcional programming: xs = [1,2,3] ys = xs.map { 2 * x } -> ys = [2,4,6]. http://code.google.com/p/tokland/wiki/RubyFunctionalProgramming

Answer (score 0):

You could use [map](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Array.html#M000249) to do this in a rubyish way:

@array = @objects.map { |o| o.value }